# how to display using asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view called StudentInfo.ascx. In it I have something like this:

```
<fieldset>
  <legend>Students Information</legend>
  <div>
     <label>First Name:</label>
     <label>Last Name:</label>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

I have another partial view called Detail.ascx which will need to display this StudentInfo.ascx. I did something like this:

```
<%= Html.RenderAction("StudentInfo"); %>
```

Is that right?

Comment: There are some problems with your post.  Detail.ascx is not a controller, it's a view.

Comment: Yes sorry its view.. what post?

Comment: The 'Post' referred to is when you posted your question. In what way did the above not work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what you intend to do and if you use strong type views etc... By the info you provided it would be better to use `RenderPartial()` but your partial view doesn't make any sense the way it is. It lacks significant details.

### RenderPartial vs. RenderAction

If you use `Html.RenderPartial()`, it will work faster, but you will have to provide the data for your partial views in a single controller action that returns the parent (partial)view.

If you use `Html.RenderAction()` it will work slower, but it gives you more flexibility and decoupling from the parent (partial)view, because data for a particular child partial view will be provided by always the same controller action that's completely independent of parent (partial)view and controller action that returned it.

### How to choose

Both are correct. It all depends on the problem at hand.

If your partial views are not strongly typed and/or they are meant for posting you will most probably display them using `RenderPartial()` extension method.

But if they do consume some data and they are strongly typed and they are used on multiple completely different views it's probably much better to use `RenderAction()`.

Think of `RenderPartial()` as a placeholder that just renders some view and `RenderAction()` as a separate MVC request pipeline. So before partial view gets rendered the whole request pipline is executed:

- request gets issued
- controller action gets invoked, prepares data and
- returns a partial view (that will be placed inside some other parent (partial)view)

So much more overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("StudentInfo") %>
```